# invalid initialization of reference type?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Whats going on?  Here is the functions it references.  I am trying to get this to work as a copy constructor

```
template <class T>
const queue<Base>& queue<T>::operator=(const queue<Base> &q){
// Doesn't need to copy if they are the same object
if (this != &q){
    delete [] data;

    length = q.length;
    capacity = q.capacity;
    front = q.front;

    data = new T[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
        data[i] = q.data[i];
    }
}

return this;
}
```

Comment: When you as a question about an error message, it is customary to specify which line produced the error. How are we supposed to know which line is line 23 (or 190)?

Comment: Why do you need an assignment operator? Use a vector instead of a raw array and the default one will work automatically.

Comment: Note that `operator=` should return a *non-const* reference.

Comment: This is the assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

Comment: You probably want to copy up to `length` rather than `capacity`.

Answer (score 2):

This is your error

```
return this;
```

`this` is a pointer. Your `operator =` is declared as returning a reference. A pointer cannot be converted to a reference. This is what the error message is telling you.